# Covert months represented as integer into dates

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

I am trying to convert months in the following format:

```r
histdata <- c("198001", "198002", "198003")
```

I tried:

```r
histdata <- transform(histdata, date = as.Date(as.character(date), "%Y%m"))
```

but then all data turned to NA.

I would like to find a solution that will return a vector of dates instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
convert_date <- function(x)
{
  x <- as.character(x)
  as.POSIXct(paste0(substr(x, 1, 4), "-", substr(x, 5, 6), "-01"))
}
```

So that you have:

```
convert_date(c(198002, 198003, 202001))
# [1] "1980-02-01 GMT" "1980-03-01 GMT" "2020-01-01 GMT"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(readr)
ym <- c("198001", "198002", "198003")
parse_date(ym, format = "%Y%m")
```

or

```
library(readr)
ym <- c(198001, 198002, 198003)
parse_date(as.character(ym), format = "%Y%m")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `base` function `as.Date` with first day of the month added to your representation of the month:

```r
as.Date(paste0(as.character(201901L), "01"), format = "%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: But still in the data frame the format is the same when I hit str(histdata) and head(histdata)

Comment: I guess you just need to assign new values to the column in your data.frame

Comment: Yes but your code replaces all dates in the column with the same data 2019 etc.

Comment: `as.Date(paste0(as.character(histdata), "01"), format = "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: I just demonstrated that this works on one value, you can pass your vector and it should still work. Also have a look at answers on the other question, it might help.